# Unknown modifier 'v' when using preg_match() expression in regex

Tags: php, regex

```
        $regex = '/\b'.$keyword.'\b/i'; // case insensitive match
        if (preg_match($regex, $linkedin_html) == 0)
        {
            $this->_htmlValidationFailed++;
            continue;                
        }
```

When I use this code.. i get error as unknown modifier 'v'..

pls let me know what is the problem and help me rectify.

Comment: What is `$keyword`? Probably it have a `/v` and you need `escape` it.

Comment: it is some expression fetched from internet.

Comment: Try it: `$regex = '/\b' . preg_quote($keyword) . '\b/i';`

Comment: Impossible to answer unless you show us what the value of `$keyword` is. I suspect, like David, it contains something the REGEX engine is attempting to parse as REGEX grammar.

Comment: we cant know what $keyword is beforehand.. it is some required information fetched from internet while running the code.. and each time it varies for different input.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$keyword = preg_quote( $keyword, '/' );

$regex = '/\b'.$keyword.'\b/i'; // case insensitive match
if (preg_match($regex, $linkedin_html) == 0)
{
   $this->_htmlValidationFailed++;
   continue;                
}
```

Comment: thanks berry.. but now it says..Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: regular expression is too large at offset #######.

Comment: @NarenKarthik Well, I'm guessing that means that your regular expression is too large ;)  If you're just testing for keywords, maybe a loop with strstr is a better fit than a regular expression?